unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers
Trying to implement B2C custom policy which allow login with MSFT accounts (Personal, School & Work)
Referred this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
I have created new app registration in Azure Portal but this above link says I have to choose select personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) but there is no such option available

So I choose option 2 Any Microsoft Enfra Id tenant - Multitenant
And also made sure in manifest of app registration these values exist i.e.
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

I have configured Technical Profile & User Journey as mentioned in above link but I am getting this error

and this is how URL looks like
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=dg+B2uAXd8VgMsdIvfw/jQ==&prompt=login&state=StateProperties=eyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6MzQ5ODRiNDgtMTI1ZC00N2ZlLTg3ZWUtYjFjZWY5OWE1MmI4IiwiVElEIjoiYWY3NWRlM2MtMzljNS00ZWEwLTkxOTktNzQxZTllOWNhZDc1IiwiVE9JRCI6IjM4Y2Y4NGUxLTRjYmItNGFiYi04YWEzLTRjMGY3MTA3YzU4NSJ9

I was mistaken and I thought my changes in app manifest that i mentioned above  are applied but some how those were not saved and once I reapplied and made sure its saved then everything start working :)

The error occurred as you are using application registered with supported type as multi-tenant instead of personal Microsoft account.
Initially, I too got same error when I registered multi-tenant application and used it to login with MSFT accounts:

To resolve the error, you need to switch to Microsoft Entra ID tenant to create personal Microsoft application, not Azure AD B2C tenant:

In this Microsoft Entra ID tenant, you can register application with personal Microsoft accounts as Supported account type as below:

Now create client secret in above application and edit B2C_1A_MSASecret policy key with secret value:

When I ran the custom policy by replacing client ID with newly created app ID, I got login screen to sign in with MSFT account as below:

After successful authentication, I got the tokens in jwt.ms website as below:

UPDATE:
If still the error persists, make sure to update below changes in your App's Manifest and Save as you mentioned in comments:
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"



I would accept this as answer but in my case I cannot see this type of account option as mentioned in my question and I only see option three options and there is nothing for personal account. I also mentioned in my account about manifest change but I was mistaken as my changes were not there so once I updated the app manifest with correct accessTokenAcceptedVersion & signInAudience and made sure its saved then everything start working

Usually, personal account option won't be available in Azure AD B2C tenants and you can only see these 3 account types while registering application https://i.imgur.com/D47uvCL.png. If you prefer using B2C application only, you can update accessTokenAcceptedVersion & signInAudience properties in App's Manifest to make it work. I added this point as an UPDATE and edited the answer, please check
